# How to automatically terminate ssh connection after starting a script in tmux window?

Tags: linux, bash, session, ssh, tmux

I'm trying to run a script in a tmux environment on another computer using ssh, but the ssh connection won't terminate until the script has finished. Let me explain this in detail:

This is test_ssh.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

name="computername"
ssh $name /bin/bash <<\EOF
    cd /scratch
    mkdir test
    cd test
    cp /home/user/test_tmux3.sh .
    tmux -c ./test_tmux3.sh &
    echo 1   # at this point it waits until test_tmux3.sh is finished, instead of exiting :(
EOF
```

This is test_tmux3.sh (as a test to see if anything happens):

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir 0min
sleep 60
mkdir 1min
sleep 60
mkdir 2min
```

At the end I would like to loop over multiple computers ($name) to start a script on each of them. The problem I am having right now is that test_ssh.sh waits after the echo 1 and only exits after tmux -c test_tmux3.sh & is finished (after 2 minutes). If I manually enter control-C test_ssh.sh stops and tmux -c test_tmux3.sh & continues running on the computer $name (which is what I want). How can automate that last step and get ssh to exit on its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the command in a detached `tmux` session.

```
#!/bin/bash

name="computername"
ssh $name /bin/bash <<\EOF
    mkdir /scratch/test
    cd /scratch/test
    cp /home/user/test_tmux3.sh .
    tmux new-session -d ./test_tmux3.sh
    echo 1
EOF
```

Now, the `tmux` command will exit as soon as the new session is created and the script is started in that session.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use nohup command to tell to the process keep running after exit?:

```
#!/bin/bash

name="computername"
ssh $name /bin/bash <<\EOF
    cd /scratch
    mkdir test
    cd test
    cp /home/user/test_tmux3.sh .
    nohup tmux -c ./test_tmux3.sh &
    echo 1   # at this point it waits until test_tmux3.sh is finished, instead of exiting :(
EOF
```

Comment: Adding nohup in front of tmux did not change anything